# Transforming dataset from text file format to "presto-orc" format for better prestoDB performance

Tags: presto

I checked this blog https://code.facebook.com/posts/370832626374903/even-faster-data-at-the-speed-of-presto-orc/.

How can I use this "presto-orc" file format ?

I have my data in S3 in text format. I want to rewrite in "presto-orc" format.

I use hive in general to write data into ORC/RCFile/Parquet.

Comment: Did you actually read that blog? It is about a custom **reader** *(i.e. custom de-serializer, the DE in SERDE)* with optimisations specific to Presto query patterns. The data **format** does not change!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no special "presto-orc" format. Presto has an optimized reader for the standard ORC format (and the Facebook DWRF variant).

You can write the files in ORC data using any program that supports it: Hive, Presto, Spark, etc.